# Mono. IPC "Connection refused" error in Debian

Tags: c#, linux, mono, debian, ipc

My configuration is Debian 9.3 (32 bit, mono v4.6.2(or 5.4) mono-complete install, apache v2.4.25 with mod_mono, .net 4.0).

When I call mono-service method from web-service through the ipc channel, an error occurs(there is **no** error on a same conf: ubuntu 16.04(32bit, mono v4.6.2 mono-complete install, apache v2.4.18 with mod_mono, .net 4.0):

> "Connection refused"  stack= Server stack trace:    at
>   Mono.Remoting.Channels.Unix.HostConnectionPool.CreateConnection ()
>   [0x00030] in &lt;ebe430c916fe49219627b20fd4c89313&gt;:0    at
>   Mono.Remoting.Channels.Unix.HostConnectionPool.GetConnection ()
>   [0x000bb] in &lt;ebe430c916fe49219627b20fd4c89313&gt;:0    at
>   Mono.Remoting.Channels.Unix.UnixConnectionPool.GetConnection
>   (System.String path) [0x00049] in
>   &lt;ebe430c916fe49219627b20fd4c89313&gt;:0    at
>   Mono.Remoting.Channels.Unix.UnixClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage
>   (System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage msg,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders requestHeaders,
>   System.IO.Stream requestStream,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders&amp;
>   responseHeaders, System.IO.Stream&amp; responseStream) [0x00025]
>   in &lt;ebe430c916fe49219627b20fd4c89313&gt;:0    at
>   Mono.Remoting.Channels.Unix.UnixBinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage
>   (System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage msg) [0x0006c] in
>   &lt;ebe430c916fe49219627b20fd4c89313&gt;:0
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:    at &lt;0x00000 + 0x00000&gt;
>   &lt;unknown method&gt;   at (wrapper remoting-invoke)
>   Common.Proxy.IMyProxy:GetInfo
>   (string)   at MyService.GetInfo
>   (System.String textt)

I create ipc channel in mono-service:

```
string PortName = "IPC_Srv5";
string HostName = "MyProxyHost.rem";
IDictionary properties = new Hashtable();
properties["portName"] = PortName;
properties["secure"] = false;
properties["priority"] = 10;
SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);
DiscretionaryAcl dacl = new DiscretionaryAcl(false, false, 1);
// Allow acces from all authenticated users
dacl.AddAccess(AccessControlType.Allow, sid, -1,
    InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.None);
CommonSecurityDescriptor securityDescriptor =
    new CommonSecurityDescriptor(false, false,
        ControlFlags.GroupDefaulted |
        ControlFlags.OwnerDefaulted |
        ControlFlags.DiscretionaryAclPresent,
        null, null, null, dacl);
// Create Formatter with full access;
BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider provider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
provider.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;
// Create an instance of a channel
IpcServerChannel srvChannel = new IpcServerChannel(properties,provider);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(srvChannel, false);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
    typeof(MyProxy),
    HostName,
    WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);

//my class
public class MyProxy : MarshalByRefObject, IMyProxy
```

Service MyService.asmx:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetInfo(string textt)
{
    string PortName = "IPC_Srv5";
    string HostName = "MyProxyHost.rem";
    var rt = (IMyProxy)System.Activator.GetObject(typeof( IMyProxy ), "ipc://" + PortName + "/" + HostName ); // no error
    return rt.GetInfo("testt");   //ERROR "Connection refused"
}
```

IMyProxy class has method: 
System.String GetInfo (System.String textt)

Don't know what is wrong. Why it works on Ubuntu on a same configuration, but error occurs on Debian. Mb needs special version of mono, apache etc? No ideas

Comment: `CONNECTION REFUSED` means the server is not bound to the socket you are trying to connect to.

Comment: @MattClark as I understood, problem with creating channel when my mono-service started, not debian environment(mono, etc..)?

Comment: I get the same error on Ubuntu when the mono-service is not running and i try to connect. 
But on Debian there is no error while mono-service starting and file "IPC_Srv5" is created in the directory /tmp